# Vectorization/data.table - increase efficiency of for loop for 12kk records DF

Tags: r, loops, data.table, vectorization

I need to associate the group to 20k groups which total amounts to 12M rows.

To solve this problem I wrote a for loop but it is clearly totally inefficient and I am sure this task can be easily vectorized. However, I am struggling in understanding how to write this instruction in a vectorized fashion.

The problem is the following:
I have an auxiliary_table with 3 features: ID, start_row, end_Row.
start_row is the row index of the first element in my_DF belonging to ID *x*;
end_row is the row index of the last element in my_DF belonging to ID *x*.

The vectorized instruction should do the following:

Considering the auxiliary_table like the following:

```
auxiliary_table <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4), start_row = c(1,4,8,13), end_row = c(3,7,12,14))
```

Considering a DF like the following:

```
  my_df <- data.frame(Var_a = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,6,4,3,1,2,1,1)
```

We need to associate the ID based on the start_row and end_row index information contained in the auxiliary_table.

The solution_df is:

```
solution_df <- data.frame(my_df, ID=(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4)
```

I asked for a vectorization of the for loop but I am open for example to data.table solutions.

I hope I was clear and presented my question correctly.

Comment: would really appreciate if there were some examples of the data; what the input looks like, what the output should look lke...

Comment: Sorry I forgot to format my_df as code, however, I presented my_df, the auxiliary_table used to index my_df and solution_df representing the solution to the task. Should I present anything else??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `auxiliary_table` is kind of *run-length encoded*. Therefore, I suggest to try the `inverse.rle()` function with an appropriately transformed   `auxiliary_table`:

#### 1. dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
my_df %>%
  mutate(ID = auxiliary_table %>% 
           transmute(lengths = end_row - start_row + 1L, values = ID) %>% 
           inverse.rle())
```

> ```
>    Var_a ID
> 1      1  1
> 2      2  1
> 3      3  1
> 4      1  2
> 5      2  2
> 6      3  2
> 7      4  2
> 8      6  3
> 9      4  3
> 10     3  3
> 11     1  3
> 12     2  3
> 13     1  4
> 14     1  4
> ```

#### 2. data.table

This adds the `ID` column without copying `my_df`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(my_df)[, ID := inverse.rle(setDT(auxiliary_table)[
  , .(lengths = end_row - start_row + 1L, values = ID)])][]
```

Depending on the size of `auxiliary_table` the code below might be somewhat more efficient because it transforms `auxiliary_table` *in place*:

> ```
> setDT(my_df)[, ID := inverse.rle(setDT(auxiliary_table)[
>   , lengths := end_row - start_row + 1L][
>     , c("end_row", "start_row") := NULL][
>       , setnames(.SD, "ID", "values")])][]
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much. 
I found difficult learning Data Table, do you have any material/website to suggest me for understanding how to write this very useful stuff, please?

Comment: A good starting point are the links provided on the `data.table` home page https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started, in particular the vignettes. It helps if you have a understanding of SQL.

Comment: Thank you really much Uwe, you can't understand how much you helped me!

Comment: I was applying your algorithm on a similar task. The difference between the new task is that sometimes `start_row == end_row`, therefore, in such cases the `ID` must be associated only to one element which `row.number == start_row == end_row`. However, I receive the following problem: `Supplied 16449900 items to be assigned to 13812131 items of column 'ID' (2637769 unused)`

Comment: Do you have any suggestion about how to modify the code to consider that exception?

Comment: Hmm, the `inverse.rle()` should be working also in case of length 1 (`start_row == end_row`). SO, I suspect that there is another problem with the other data set. Please, post a new question showing the other data.

Answer (score 1):

I have designed a user defined function and applying it on the `auxillary_table`. See if this helps -

```
auxiliary_table <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4), start_row = c(1,4,8,13), end_row = c(3,7,12,14))
my_df <- data.frame(Var_a = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,6,4,3,1,2,1,1))
solution_df <- data.frame(my_df, ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4))

aux_to_df <- function(aux_row){
  # 1,2,3 can be replaced by column names
  value = aux_row[1]
  start_row = aux_row[2]
  end_row = aux_row[3]

  my_df[start_row:end_row, "ID"] <<- value # <<- means assigning to global out of scope variable
}

apply(auxiliary_table, 1, aux_to_df)
my_df
```

Comment: Unfortunately apply function is not more efficient than doing the same operation using a for loop.

Comment: you might want to cast it using `as.matrix()` that might help. Short of this, there isn't much you will be able to do I guess

Comment: I am sure there is an extremely efficient way to do this